# ROW_NUMBER() on informix DB shows BIGINT is not supported

Tags: java, jdbc, informix

I am trying to add row numbers to a sql query to get a return resultset, but the JDBC does not support BIGINT it says. I look up https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.9/ref/rreffuncrownumber.html and https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_11.50.0/com.ibm.jdbc_pg.doc/ids_jdbc_141.htm.

The code:

```
String query = new StringBuilder("SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER() AS id, * FROM "+tableName).toString();
```

Error:

> [Informix JDBC Driver][Informix]The data type bigint is not supported for current client/server configuration.

The IBM solution tells you to use getBigSerial() to get the BIGINT after the insert. However, I want to find a way to be able to add some auto increment numbers when it queries the table without creating an actual column. Is there a way?

Comment: Which version of the JDBC driver are you using?  Version 11.50 is quite old, almost out of support if not out of support.  Which version of Informix are you using?  Is it 11.50?  I think not because the OLAP notations like `OVER()` are not supported until late 11.70 or 12.10.

Comment: I installed 12.10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Casting is good:

```
String query = "SELECT CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER() AS INT) AS id, * FROM "+tableName;
```

I test it with my informix database and it works.

Answer (score 1):

You can cast it to VARCHAR in the query.

You can cast that String into BigInteger in Java code if you use it for something more than present it to the client.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. How exactly can I do that? I was supposed to use statement.executeQuery(query) to get a ResultSet object. And the id will be auto generated. When I do rs.nest(), I will see an extra column which the id will be provided. I use row_number() on SQL Server, Oracle, and PostgreSQL databases. They all work fine.